# How to only run methods when called?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, methods

I have a bunch of code below.  However, I am hitting some bugs because the methods Move() and Genius() are running logic too much.  I only want to two methods to run if they are being called by the submit click method.  How can I do this?

```
namespace ShotgunApp
{
    public partial class SingleGame : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static class AmmoCount
        {
            public static int userAmmo = startVars.startAmmo;
            public static int geniusAmmo = startVars.startAmmo;
        }

        public static class Global
        {
            public static int lives = 1;
            public static string GeniusMove;
            public static string UserMove;
        }

        public SingleGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GeniusAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.geniusAmmo;
            UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.userAmmo;   
        }

        private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((String)submit.Content) == "Submit")
            {
                Move();
                submit.Content = "Wait for Genius...";
                uReload.IsEnabled = false;
                uFire.IsEnabled = false;
                uShield.IsEnabled = false;
                Genius();
            }
            else if (((String)submit.Content) == "Go!")
            {
                GeniusSpeak.Text = "";
                OutcomeDesc.Text = "You have " + Move() + " and Genius has " + Genius();
                Outcome.Text = "ANOTHER ROUND...";
                submit.Content = "Continue";
            }
            else if (((String)submit.Content) == "Continue")
            {

                uReload.IsEnabled = true;
                uFire.IsEnabled = true;
                uShield.IsEnabled = true;
                OutcomeDesc.Text = "";
                Outcome.Text = "";
                submit.Content = "Submit";
            }
        }


        public string Move()
        { 
            if (uReload.IsChecked.HasValue && uReload.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + ++AmmoCount.userAmmo;
                Global.UserMove = "reloaded";

            }
            else if (uShield.IsChecked.HasValue && uShield.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                Global.UserMove = "shielded";
            }
            else if (uFire.IsChecked.HasValue && uFire.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + --AmmoCount.userAmmo;
                Global.UserMove = "fired";

            }
            else
            {
                submit.Content = "Enter a move!";
            }

            return Global.UserMove;
        }

        public string Genius()
        {
            GeniusSpeak.Text = "Genius has moved";
            submit.Content = "Go!";

            Random RandomNumber = new Random();
            int x = RandomNumber.Next(0, 3);

            if (x == 0)
            {
                Global.GeniusMove = "reloaded";
                GeniusAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + ++AmmoCount.geniusAmmo;
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                Global.GeniusMove = "shielded";
            }
            else if (x == 2)
            {
                Global.GeniusMove = "fired";
                GeniusAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + ++AmmoCount.geniusAmmo;
            }

            return Global.GeniusMove;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only call `Move` and `Genius` from `submit_Click` already. What is the problem?

Comment: "I only want to two methods to run if they are being called by the submit click method." - unless I misunderstand the statement; then *don't call them from other places*... what am I missing?

Comment: But I'm only calling them from submit_Click, they still run by themselves when the program flow gets there.  I only want to run them when submit is clicked.

Comment: if this is all of your code than maybe you don't understand the "program-flow" - methods won't be run if they are not called

Comment: IS there any other places that you call Move and Genius in it?? anyway you can add bool to the arguments of the the function Move(bool DoWork) and do your code inside an if condition.. it that what you mean?

Comment: Are you aware that this `OutcomeDesc.Text = "You have " + Move() + " and Genius has " + Genius();` will also run the methods?

Comment: ^^ ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.....................

Comment: not of course for me teh noob.... so how can i display those values without calling the methods again.

Comment: you are already calling them through an if else so in the same if condition it's called one time!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the last results in data members:

```
        private string lastMoveResult = string.Empty;
        private string lastGeniusResult = string.Empty;

        private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((String)submit.Content) == "Submit")
            {
                lastMoveResult = Move();
                submit.Content = "Wait for Genius...";
                uReload.IsEnabled = false;
                uFire.IsEnabled = false;
                uShield.IsEnabled = false;
                lastGeniusResult = Genius();
            }
            else if (((String)submit.Content) == "Go!")
            {
                GeniusSpeak.Text = "";
                OutcomeDesc.Text = "You have " + lastMoveResult + " and Genius has " + lastGeniusResult ;
                Outcome.Text = "ANOTHER ROUND...";
                submit.Content = "Continue";
            }
```